# Getting server error 500 in laravel 7 after user login

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-7

I have downloaded my Laravel project from hosting server. Staging server correctly loaded and work. In my local, Login and Register page was fully loaded. But I got 500 server error every time after login with my credentials. And why I need to generate

> php artisan key:generate

whenever I restart the server otherwise it show me 500 server error. I can't find any solution for the last days. It makes me headaches. Sorry for my English.

In my project root folder, I have

public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my Login controller,

```
public function userLogin(Request $request)
    {
        // login when add to cart or wishlist
        $action = $request->input('action');
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $type = $request->input('type');
        $redirect = $request->input('redirect');

        $rules = [
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
        $messages = [
            'email.required'    => __('Email is required field'),
            'email.email'       => __('Invalid email'),
            'password.required' => __('Password is required field'),
        ];
        if (ReCaptchaEngine::isEnable() and setting_item("user_enable_login_recaptcha")) {
            $codeCapcha = $request->input('g-recaptcha-response');
            if (!$codeCapcha or !ReCaptchaEngine::verify($codeCapcha)) {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Please verify the captcha')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors
                ], 200);
            }
        }
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'error'    => true,
                'messages' => $validator->errors(),
                'redirect' => false
            ], 200);
        } else {
            $email = $request->input('email');
            $password = $request->input('password');
            $request->session()->put('user_email', $email);
            //session('user_email',$email);
            $request->session()->put('user_password', $password);
            session('user_password', $password);
            $tempUser = User::where('email', $email)->first();
            $url = strip_tags($request->input('redirect')) ? strip_tags($request->input('redirect')) : url('');
            if (empty($tempUser)) {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Username or password incorrect')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors,
                    'redirect' => false
                ], 200);
            }

            if ($tempUser->status == 'blocked') {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Your account has been blocked')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors,
                    'redirect' => false
                ], 200);
            }

            // $temp = strtolower($tempUser->roles[0]->name);
            // if ($temp == "administrator") {
            //     $checkUser = Hash::check($password, $tempUser->password);

            //     if ($checkUser) {
            //         Auth::attempt([
            //             'email'    => $email,
            //             'password' => $password
            //         ], false);




            //         $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;

            //         if ($remember) {

            //             $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
            //             Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('uplyrn_email_login', $email, $lifetime));
            //             //$response_cooki->withCookie(cookie('save_email_login',Auth::user()->email , $lifetime));
            //         } else {
            //             Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('uplyrn_email_login'));
            //         }
            //         Auth::login($tempUser, $remember);
            //         if (!empty($request->input('id'))) {
            //             if ($this->handleActionLogin($action, $id, $type)) {
            //                 if (!empty($type)) {
            //                     $key = 'isWishList';
            //                     $value = "true";
            //                     $request->session()->put($key, $value);
            //                 }
            //                 BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {
            //                     Cart::add($item->course, 1);
            //                 });
            //                 return response()->json([
            //                     'error'    => false,
            //                     'messages' => false,
            //                     'redirect' => $redirect
            //                 ], 200);
            //             }
            //         }

            //         BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {
            //             Cart::add($item->course, 1);
            //         });
            //         return response()->json(
            //             [
            //                 'error'    => false,
            //                 'messages' => false,
            //                 'redirect' => '/admin'
            //             ]
            //         );
            //     } else {
            //         $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Username or password incorrect')]);
            //         return response()->json([
            //             'error'    => true,
            //             'messages' => $errors,
            //             'redirect' => false
            //         ], 200);
            //     }
            // }
            $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;

            if (Auth::attempt([
                'email'    => $email,
                'password' => $password
            ], $remember)) {
                $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;
                Auth::login($tempUser, $remember);
                Auth::logoutOtherDevices($password);
                if (in_array(Auth::user()->status, ['blocked'])) {
                    Auth::logout();
                    $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Your account has been blocked')]);
                    return response()->json([
                        'error'    => true,
                        'messages' => $errors,
                        'redirect' => false
                    ], 200);
                }

                $remember = !empty($request->remember) ? true : false;

                if ($remember) {

                    $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // one year
                    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('uplyrn_email_login', $email, $lifetime));
                    //$response_cooki->withCookie(cookie('save_email_login',Auth::user()->email , $lifetime));
                } else {
                    Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('uplyrn_email_login'));
                }
                Auth::login($tempUser, $remember);
                // $url = strip_tags($request->input('redirect'));
                // $url = url('');

                if (isset(Auth::user()->roles) && !empty(Auth::user()->roles)) {
                    if (isset(Auth::user()->roles[0])) {
                        switch (strtolower(Auth::user()->roles[0]->name)) {
                            case 'administrator':
                            case 'admin':
                                //$url .= '/admin';
                                Auth::logout();
                                $request->input('redirect') ? $url : $url .= '/show2Fa';
                                break;
                            case 'lecturer':
                                $request->input('redirect') ? $url : $url .= '/user/profile ';
                                break;
                            case 'student':
                            case 'customer':
                                $request->input('redirect') ? $url : $url .= '/all-courses';
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($request->input('id'))) {
                    if ($this->handleActionLogin($action, $id, $type)) {
                        if (!empty($type)) {

                            $key = 'isWishList';
                            $value = "true";
                            $request->session()->put($key, $value);
                        }
                        BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {

                            Cart::add($item->course, 1);
                        });
                        return response()->json([
                            'error'    => false,
                            'messages' => false,
                            'redirect' => $redirect,
                        ], 200);
                    }
                }

                BravoCart::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->get()->each(function ($item) {

                    Cart::add($item->course, 1);
                });

                // var_dump(auth()->user());
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => false,
                    'messages' => false,
                    'redirect' => $url ? e($url) : url(app_get_locale(false, '/'))
                ], 200);
            } else {
                $errors = new MessageBag(['message_error' => __('Username or password incorrect')]);
                return response()->json([
                    'error'    => true,
                    'messages' => $errors,
                    'redirect' => false
                ], 200);
            }
        }
    }
```

After login from controller I returned Json data to my ajax success method. In my seccess method, I redirect route to (127.0.0.1:8000/) that is from **data.redirect**. After that I got 500 server error.

```
$.ajax({
      url: bookingCore.routes.login,
      data: {
        email: form.find('input[name=email]').val(),
        password: form.find('input[name=password]').val(),
        remember: form.find('input[name=remember]').is(':checked') ? 1 : '',
        'g-recaptcha-response': form.find('[name=g-recaptcha-response]').val(),
        redirect: form.find('input[name=redirect]').val(),
        action: form.find('input[name=action]').val(),
        id: form.find('input[name=id]').val(),
        type: form.find('input[name=type]').val(),
      },
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function() {
        form.find('.error').hide();
        form.find('.icon-loading').css('display', 'inline-block');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        form.find('.icon-loading').hide();
        if (data.error === true) {
          if (data.messages !== undefined) {
            for (var item in data.messages) {
              var msg = data.messages[item];
              console.log(item);
              form
                .find('.error-' + item)
                .show()
                .text(msg[0]);
            }
          }
          if (data.messages.message_error !== undefined) {
            $('.form-right-question p').addClass('form-right-question-change');
            form
              .find('.message-error')
              .show()
              .html(
                '<div class="message-login">' +
                  data.messages.message_error[0] +
                  '</div>'
              );
          }
        }
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.redirect !== undefined && data.redirect) {
          window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }
      },
    });
```

Here is my log file

[image: error log file]

Is there anything I miss, thanks before, sorry for bad English.

Comment: Log file saying there is no offset in array in header.blade.php - maybe there you have something like reading user's name?

Comment: Can you show header.blade.php?